# I have a domain name. What is the cheapest or free way I can forward email to those domain to a gmail?

Tags: domains

Basically I want an email alias.

I suppose I can use google workspace that cost $4 per month.

Just simple forwarding. No need for full email.

I wonder if we even need 3rd party for this?

Do registrar have ways to do it for free?

Comment: "google workspace that cost $4 per month" - From the UK, it's 5 GBP/month (billed annually), which is 6.45 USD/month!?

Comment: Looks like my registrar allow this sort of thing for free